# Does a List object get passed by reference?

Tags: java, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Java pass-by-reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Does a `List` object get passed by reference? In other words, if I pass an `ArrayList (java.util.ArrayList)` object to a class, will it be automatically updated when I change it?

Comment: Hint: `ArrayList` or `List` is not special in this regard. In fact **no class** is special in this regard.

Comment: All primitives and references are *passed by value* in Java. In your case you have a reference to a List (not a List as such) and the reference to it will be passed by value.

Answer (score 41):

> in other word: If I pass an ArrayList (java.util.ArrayList) object to a class, will it be automatically updated when I change it?

Yes

> Does the List object passed by reference?

Value of reference would get passed

```
public updateList(List<String> names){
 //..
}
```

**Explanation**

When you call `updateList(someOtherList);` the value of `someOtherList` which is a reference will copied to `names` (another reference in method, bit by bit) so now both of them are referring to same instance in memory and thus it will change

---

**See**

- [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, a `List` that you pass to a method is passed by reference.  Any objects you add to the `List` inside the method will still be in the `List` after the method returns.

Answer (score 7):

If you add to a list in one method, its original reference in first method will also contain the new item.

[java is pass by value, and for objects this means the reference is passed by value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/106261).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because You just pass a reference of `ArrayList`-Object, to your `Object`.