# ArrayList from one class to another

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I have read quite a few pages of stackoverflow but I wasn't able to get my ArrayList to get copied unto another class. Here's the scenario, I'm building a quick book saver app, similar to what you would have in a library but simpler (for school).

I have my main library class (with the main) that has the swing set up for the main menu/options.

I have the book class with the constructor for new books as follows:

```
public class Livre {

private String titre;
private String soustitre;
private String auteur;
private String editeur;
private String collection;
private String isbn;
private long cup;
private double prixDeVenteSuggere;
private double prixVente;
private int nbPages;
private boolean disponible;

public Livre(String titre, String soustitre, String auteur, String editeur, String collection, String isbn, long cup, double prixDeVenteSuggere, double prixVente, int nbPages, boolean disponible){
    this.titre = titre;
    this.soustitre = soustitre;
    this.auteur = auteur;
    this.editeur = editeur;
    this.collection = collection;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.cup = cup;
    this.prixDeVenteSuggere = prixDeVenteSuggere;
    this.prixVente = prixVente;
    this.nbPages = nbPages;
    disponible = true;
}

public Livre() {

}

public String getTitre() {
    return titre;
}

public void setTitre(String titre) {
    this.titre = titre;
}

public String getSoustitre() {
    return soustitre;
}

public void setSoustitre(String soustitre) {
    this.soustitre = soustitre;
}

public String getAuteur() {
    return auteur;
}

public void setAuteur(String auteur) {
    this.auteur = auteur;
}

public String getEditeur() {
    return editeur;
}

public void setEditeur(String editeur) {
    this.editeur = editeur;
}

public String getCollection() {
    return collection;
}

public void setCollection(String collection) {
    this.collection = collection;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public long getCup() {
    return cup;
}

public void setCup(long cup) {
    this.cup = cup;
}

public double getPrixDeVenteSuggere() {
    return prixDeVenteSuggere;
}

public void setPrixDeVenteSuggere(double prixDeVenteSuggere) {
    this.prixDeVenteSuggere = prixDeVenteSuggere;
}

public double getPrixVente() {
    return prixVente;
}

public void setPrixVente(double prixVente) {
    this.prixVente = prixVente;
}

public int getNbPages() {
    return nbPages;
}

public void setNbPages(int nbPages) {
    this.nbPages = nbPages;
}

public boolean isDisponible() {
    return disponible;
}

public void setDisponible(boolean disponible) {
    this.disponible = disponible;
}
```

}

Option #1 on the Library class (built with WindowBuilder) has the "New" button which opens a second `JFrame` to input all the info in regards to the book.

in this `JFrame` class, I've added an `actionListener` on the confirm button to confirm the input on the `JTextFields` to be added as an object as follows:

```
public void confirmerLivre(){
    l = new Livre(txtTitre.getText(), txtSousTitre.getText(), txtAuteur.getText(), 
                    txtEditeur.getText(), txtCollection.getText(), txtISBN.getText(), 
                    Long.parseLong(txtCodebar.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtPrixMSRP.getText()), 
                    Double.parseDouble(txtPrix.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtPages.getText()), true);

    confirmerLivre.add(l); /// confirmerLivre is defined as an ArrayList
}
```

What I can't wrap my head around is being able to take the `ArrayList` confirmerLivre from the 2nd `JFrame` class and push it unto my main `JFrame` class to be manipulated further with other options.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the quickest fix is to create/expose these methods in your main JFrame class:

- `getBookList()`
- `setBookList()`

When you create your popup JFrame, you need to pass an instance of your main JFrame class to it in its constructor:

```
public PopupFrame extends JFrame {
  private MainFrame main;
  public PopupFrame(MainFrame main) {
    this.main = main;
  }
}
```

Now that you have access to your main JFrame class from your popup, you can just go `main.getBookList()` to get the list (I'd recommend reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397008/does-a-list-object-get-passed-by-reference) also)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, there's an answer below with access to the ArrayList between classes thanks to its global scope but with your getter/setter method is the one the teacher needs to see. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

If you create your `ArrayList` as a public variable in the second `JFrame` class (outside any of the methods) then it can be used in the first class such as:

```
SecondJFramesName.confirmerLivre()
```

In this code `SecondJFramesName` is the name of your second `JFrame` class. Now that your `ArrayList` is a public variable it can be accessed outside the class.

Note: your second `JFrame`'s name is the one you use to create it in a way such as this:

```
JFrame SecondJFramesName = new JFrame("My title");
```

If you need any more specific details please comment!

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you 100 times, this works. The getter/setter method is the one I need to go with due to teacher's constraints.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it helped. Also if you think it is a good answer upvote it (click the up arrow next to the number on the left) so other people who view the question know!

Comment: I did, but since my reputation points are below 15 it apparently doesn't publicly show. I'll be back once it hits 15

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_patern) could help you:

```
public interface ConfirmerLivreMonitor{
    void onConfirmerLivreChange(List<...> confirmerLivre);
}
```

then

```
//...
private ConfirmerLivreMonitor confirmerLivreMonitor;
public void setConfirmerLivreMonitor(ConfirmerLivreMonitor confirmerLivreMonitor ){
    this.confirmerLivreMonitor = confirmerLivreMonitor 
}
//....
public void confirmerLivre(){
    l = new Livre(txtTitre.getText(), txtSousTitre.getText(), txtAuteur.getText(), 
                    txtEditeur.getText(), txtCollection.getText(), txtISBN.getText(), 
                    Long.parseLong(txtCodebar.getText()), Double.parseDouble(txtPrixMSRP.getText()), 
                    Double.parseDouble(txtPrix.getText()), Integer.parseInt(txtPages.getText()), true);

    confirmerLivre.add(l); /// confirmerLivre is defined as an ArrayList

    if(confirmerLivreMonitor != null){   //notify confirmerLivre change
       confirmerLivreMonitor.onConfirmerLivreChange(confirmerLivre);
    }
}
```

make the Main JFrame implemnents ConfirmerLivreMonitor,so you can:

```
sencondJFrame.setConfirmerLivreMonitor(this);
```

or just pass a anonymous class:

```
sencondJFrame.setConfirmerLivreMonitor(new ConfirmerLivreMonitor(){

        public void onConfirmerLivreChange(List<...> confirmerLivre){
            //display in Main JFrame,maybe
        }
});
```

once the confirmerLivre change, the main frame can display(or something else) 
 the first time,very cool